# Cube roots of unity problem

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

If $1,w, w^2$ are cube roots of unity, then what would be the value of $w^2(1+w)^3-(1+w^2)w$? 
Any help regarding how to solve or formulate this further would be great.

All I know is $1+w+w^2=0$.

Comment: Hint. Multiply everything out. You also know $w^3 = 1$.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint** $$1+w=-w^2 \\
1+w^2=-w .$$

Replace them.